# Liferay overriding JSONAction using hook

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

Liferay has feature to modify Struts Action using hook which is straight-forward. However I am trying to override getJSON method of RateEntryAction.

The use case is I need total positive score and total negative score instead of average score that Liferay's OOTB rating component provides.

I already have necessary methods readily available in Liferay API to get the total positive and negative scores. I created a custom type just like "stars" and "votes" to write my necessary logic in hook. I was then planning to override struts action represented by /portal/rate_enty to override the method and add negative and positive votes in the json that is already being returned.

But RateEntryAction (which is the original class) is extending JSONAction and overriding getJSON method. Is it possible to override just getJSON method using struts action hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see this action class in struts-config.xml, so it's a Struts Action.
This is the path you could try to override.

```
<action path="/portal/rate_entry" type="com.liferay.portal.action.RateEntryAction" />
```

I would try to override this path, and see if can put your logic there.

RateEntryAction extends from JSONAction , and this one from org.apache.struts.action.Action  , which is the same class that PortletAction extends.

Hope this help

Comment: That's what I had earlier done. But getJson cannot be overrided. I had to override execute method

Answer (score 2):

As per my research we can only hook *com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletAction*  sub classes, Yeah JSONAction also extend *org.apache.struts.action.Action* class same as PortletAction, but liferay allow only those classes hookable which comes under PortletAction class not except that.

Answer (score 1):

As RateEntryAction is not a Struts Action, you can't overload it with a Struts Action Hook. I'm not aware of any hookable way to override it, thus my best guess is that you'll have to either go for ext or introduce a whole new JSON API function and hook all places in Liferay that refer to the original implementation to now go to your implementation.

I suspect that in this case an ext plugin will be easier to maintain. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actual RateEntryAction extends JSONAction which extends StrutsAction, so technically RateEntryAction is a struts action

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I missed Action's package name and got distracted by the indirection, secretly assuming the wrong thing. My bad, sorry for misleading you. Looks like @Joaco1977 found the answer, upvoting that one.